# How to set an initial value for an object key?

Tags: javascript

I have an object, where the user is an object, and firstly I check from an array if one of it's elements equals to the criteria. It's not always the case, and if it doesn't exist in the array, I want to return an empty object (instead of `undefined`):

```js
//...
return {
  user: users.find(user => user.uid === selectedUser)
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Maybe I did wrong something else, but for developers in the future who needs the answer to the same question, answer it, and I'll accept it. Also, I remove the comment from my snippet to not make confuse in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) (`||`) operator. This will return the first [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value it encounters. This means that if the `find()` returns `undefined` it will return the value on the right side of the `||`.

```
return {
  user: users.find(user => user.uid === selectedUser) || {}
}
```

You can see an example here:

```js
function findUser(selectedUser) {
  const users = [{
    uid: 1,
    name: 'John'
  }, {
    uid: 2,
    name: 'Doe'
  }];

  return {
    user: users.find(user => user.uid === selectedUser) || {}
  }
}

console.log(findUser(1));
console.log(findUser(2));
console.log(findUser(3));
```